# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT return only one value

Tags: mysql

I try to return how many friends a user have through `GROUP_CONCAT` But i only get `Lance`  and not also `Bob` and it seems if i remove the `WHERE` condition. It works fine, but i would like to keep it. Since i want get all rows which are connected to `member`

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO users (name)
VALUES ("Gregor"),
    ("Liza"),
    ("Matt"),
    ("Tim"),
    ("Lance"),
    ("Bob");
    
CREATE TABLE committee(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT,
    friend_id INT,
    member_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`friend_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`member_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO committee (user_id, friend_id, member_id)
VALUES (3, 5, 1),
(4, 5, 1),
(3, 6, 2),
(4, 6, 2);
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) AS friends
FROM committee c
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = c.user_id)
INNER JOIN users AS f ON (f.id = c.friend_id)
WHERE (c.member_id = 1)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

What i get now:

```
name    friends
Matt    Lance
Tim Lance
```

What i expect:

```
name    friends
Matt    Lance,Bob
Tim Lance,Bob
```

Comment: Please explain why you expect to see Bob?  Your query just finds two committee rows, the matt/lance/gregor row and the tim/lance/gregor row.  What is is that is supposed to make Bob be included?

Comment: Since `bob` is also a friend to Matt and Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another join with `committee` to find all the other committees that Matt and Tim are on, so you can find their friends from those committees.

```
SELECT u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) AS friends
FROM committee c
INNER JOIN users u ON (u.id = c.user_id)
INNER JOIN committee c2 ON c2.user_id = c.user_id
INNER JOIN users AS f ON (f.id = c2.friend_id)
WHERE (c.member_id = 1)
GROUP BY u.id;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25cf45/5)

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfect. I have one question, i heard that less joins is better. Would you done this query any different?

Comment: It's possible to do it using `IN (SELECT ...)` but MySQL doesn't optimize them well.

Comment: I see, so this is a fine way doing this? :)

Comment: Yes, this is best. The foreign keys will make it efficient.